# Return NSArray of float NSNumbers from Objective-C to C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, unity-game-engine, marshalling

What is the best way to return a large (size = 2048) NSArray of NSNumbers like this back to C# code to be used as a float array (also of size 2048):

```
NSArray<NSNumber*> *nsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.2],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.3], nil];
```

Returning it as a float* would be ideal since I can marshal it in C#, but I'm open to suggestions.

I can always expect the size of the NSArray to be 2048 and it'll always have float values represented by NSNumber

Comment: If float * will do why not create a C array and load it up with your floats.

Comment: How would I load up the array? Is my only choice to iterate over the NSArray copy it?

Comment: See my answer where I give the detail - just a comment. It looks somewhat clumsy the way you load floats into that array in your code. That is perfect if you have just a few floats, but for a lot you need to streamline it a bit ... But that is another topic and not what you are asking.

Comment: No worries. That's not how the actual NSArray is created, that's just some example code. The actual NSArray comes from somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what is best to communicate between Objective-C and C#, but if you can use an array, this is how you can load it.

```
// Create float * array from NSArray of floats
void doIt ( NSArray < NSNumber * > * arrayOfFloats )
{
    // Need to allocate memory
    float * f = malloc( sizeof ( float ) * arrayOfFloats.count );

    // Load it
    [arrayOfFloats enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^ ( NSNumber * i, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop ) {

        f [ idx ] = i.floatValue;

    }];

    // Here you pass it to C#
    // send f to C# ...

    // Now done, so you can free f
    // If C# passing copies f then you can free
    // If it will free then you skip this step
    // I recommend you keep it otherwise you have memory leak ...
    free ( f );
}
```

This is just a C function but you can easily turn it into a class message if that will work better.

Yes you iterate over the array but still this will be pretty fast.

The *best* way depends ... amongst others on how you communicate between Objective-C and C# ... there may be a better way but, unless you can send the NSArray as is this will close to it.